# Vim: how to remap a "general" key

Tags: vim

One thing I really like in Vim is it's hability to have multiple clipboards available. However I hate to write `"ay` to yank and `"ap` to paste, I'd rather have something closer to the classical Ctrl-c, Ctrl-v, like `←a` (←: AltGr + y) and `þa` (þ: AltGr + p).

I could make a remap like `nnoremap ←a "ay` in this case, but then I would only have the buffer "a" available to use this way. So the question is: could I make a remap such as `nnoremap ←{key} "{key}y` in vim, that would replace the {key} with whatever I typed, so that I could use any character as a register with only one remap? (`←q` becomes `"qy`, `←w` becomes `"wy`, etc...)

Btw: yes, AltGr keys like "←" and "þ" works just like any other letter for commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-hand side of a mapping can't be dynamic.

The easiest way to deal with that limitation is simply to loop through a list:

```
for reg in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    execute 'nnoremap ←' .. reg .. ' "' .. reg .. 'y'
    execute 'nnoremap þ' .. reg .. ' "' .. reg .. 'p'
endfor
```

See `:help :for`, `:help :execute`, `:help expr-..`.

---

Note that `y` is an *operator* and an operator is supposed to "operate" on a motion. This means that all those `"{char}y` normal mode mappings are useless. For this to actually be useful, you would need to:

- make visual mode mappings for `y`,
- make a custom operator for use in normal mode, see `:help :map-operator`.

Comment: anyways i tried putting what you said but remaped for "J" and "K", in normal mode and in visual mode and it seems to crash when i try to use it saying this in the terminal:
```
Error detected while processing /home/njoppi2/.vimrc:
line    2:
E714: List required
line    7:
E714: List required
```
did i do anything wrong?

Comment: You might have an older build. Try replacing the `'abcd'` string with a list: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]`.

Comment: it worked with the list! and with the alt gr keys as well, thank you